# A noise in my microphone

Tags: alsa, acer, 17.04, microphone, noise

I have been using Ubuntu for a while. I have been suffering for noise while I am using the microphone for a while. I am using Acer V13.

The problem is not the Mic because it's working flawless on windows. I had an acer laptop before with the same problem with Ubuntu.

I have tried to play with ALSAMIXER for a bit but it's not helping. I either get really low volume on my mic or good volume but really noisy.

Do you have any suggestions guys. I guess this problem with all Acer laptops with Ubuntu. but I really hate using Skype or Whatsapp on my laptop. I upgraded from 14.04 to 15, 16, and now 17.04 with no improvements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* (not a certainty) that you're dealing with electrical interference generated by other electrical components in your computer. It could also be a hardware flaw (in the OP's case this sounds less likely to be the problem since it has existed across multiple machines). Maybe the driver running your sound card isn't the best.

I find that a USB audio sound cards like the one shown below are [cheap enough on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IRVQ0F8) and have fixed my sound problems (similar to OP's, though not exactly the same) in the past. I've not purchased one yet that didn't work with Ubuntu, but a lack of Linux drivers for these sounds cards is always a possibility.

When plugged in, these are separate audio devices from the built-in sound card on your computer. As such, you may need to adjust your sound settings to use the USB sound card rather than the built-in device(s).

[image: 2979795890_b29ce48e3e_b.jpg]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I will be trying another sound card on the same machine. But one thing, If the sound card is my problem or interference, why I dont have any problem in windows. I have Ubuntu and windows on the same machine. Windows has 0 problem with the mic.

Comment: Ubuntu might not operate the hardware in exactly the same manner as Windows. Consider that the drivers may not implement the exact same set of features. If the hardware is not being driven in exactly the same manner, it could, in theory, account for interference generated under one OS and not the other. That's all speculation though.

Comment: Is it possible that I can install the sound  card driver?

Comment: I can't say for sure that drivers are your issue. It's a possibility. That being said, there may not be a better driver for Linux than the one you're currently using. If it is related to the way your drivers are running the hardware, it may not even be your sound card driver. It could be other hardware. I've personally never run Linux on an Acer, so all I can really do is guess.

Comment: Thank you anyway for helping man. I really appreciate it. Still trying to figure this out :(